# How are huge python projects converted into a standalone software that runs on any windows?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, development-environment

I just finished my mini-project. I replicated a Notepad Application using pythons Tkinter Module. It consists of various features just like An original Notepad.

Now that I have finished my python project using pycharm. How can I Convert that entire file into a Standalone software that I can install and run on any Windows??

And I wanna know how huge software projects are converted into the final product??

Sorry if the Qsn's format is not right, I'm totally new to this platform

If Anyone gets interested to have a look at the Project:
Here's my Github link:

[GitHub link](https://github.com/Suman196pokhrel/Notepad-using-python)

Comment: well the Q is closed, usually we use `pyinstaller` to make an exe and then an installer with the file and then later, send it to the client. easy as that

Comment: Thank you for the reply